# c# escaping " character

Tags: c#, serialization, escaping

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

which contains field name and value, for example:

```
"code":"abcd"
"description":"some text"
...
```

I need to serialize it in this way to put it in another dictionary:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var ser = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(javascriptSerializer.Serialize(dictList ));
 body.Add("rows", ser);
```

it works but I have a problem, sometimes the description contains ", for example:

```
 "description":"some "text"
```

and it produce an error sending this body, how can I escape the " character in the description?

Comment: question: *why* are you using `Regex.Unescape` on JSON? what is it that you're actually trying to *achieve* here? Maybe if you tell us what you're trying to *do*, we can advise on better ways of achieving that outcome. Because the thing you're doing: is just... doomed.

Comment: Why do you use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape`?`It makes no sense here and produces the problem you see

Comment: I did it because  the char ' was stored as \u0027

Comment: @marko what  ' ? I don't see a  ' - and are you saying that you're seeing the *literal 6 characters* `\u0027`? or...? can we see the actual scenario that you're struggling with, because it would *really, really* help

Comment: in some descriptions I have the char ', without the Rege.Unescape it was printed as \u0027 instead of ' and I solved with the Regex.Unescape

Comment: @marko that sounds like a problem with the JSON serializer; what is `JavaScriptSerializer` here - is that the Web.Script one? yeah, don't use that; frankly, Newtonsoft is the de-facto choice these days, and: doesn't do that (I've just double checked to be sure); So... `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictList);` example output: `[{"code":"abcd","descr'iption":"some ' text"}]`